# tengo una duda sobre el método distancia de problema de poo

Tags: python, poo

El ejercicio es el siguiente:
Debemos representar un personaje de un videojuego. El personaje se mueve en un mundo de dos dimensiones (x, y) y cuando comienza el juego se encuentra ubicado en la posición (0,0) y su nivel de energía están en 10 (ese valor se inicializa siempre con 10).

El personaje tiene estos métodos asociados:

- Constructor: el método constructor -además de definir el estadio inicial- deberá recibir como parámetro el nombre del personaje (string)
- Avanzar(lista_movimientos): lista_movimientos es una lista de tuplas, donde cada tupla tiene el siguiente formato (dirección, casilleros). Dirección es un string y puede ser “norte”, “sur”, “este”, “oeste”, mientras que casilleros indica la cantidad de casilleros a moverse (será un número  entero). Por ejemplo, si el personaje ha sido recién creado (está en el origen) entonces invocar a este método Avanzar( [ (“norte”, 1), (“este”, 2) ] ) dejaría a nuestro personaje en la posición (2, 1). Tener en cuenta que cada vez que se mueve un casillero se consume una unidad de energía (en el ejemplo anterior, el primer movimiento consumió 1 y el segundo 2, por lo tanto como arrancó en 10, luego de invocar Avanzar el nivel de energía estará en 7). Un detalle: solo se realiza un movimiento si existe energía disponible para ir en esa dirección; si en el ejemplo la lista de movimientos es [ (“norte”, 9), (“este”, 2)], avanzaría hasta (0, 9), tendría 1 unidad de energía remanente y con eso no le alcanza para el segundo movimiento, por lo tanto se quedará en ese último lugar y no seguirá con el resto de los movimientos, es decir, hará todos los movimientos posibles. Cuando puede hacer todos los movimientos, los hace y listo; cuando no puede seguir con los movimientos, se queda en el último posible y debe imprimir un cartel que diga “No he podido completar el avance. Me he detenido en la posición (x, y)” donde x e y es la posición real donde quedó.
- CargarEnergia(unidades): aumenta (es decir agrega) la energía indicada al personaje
- Ubicación: devuelve una tupla con las coordenadas (x,y) del personaje
- Distancia(OtroPersonaje): devuelve la distancia que existe entre el personaje del objeto y OtroPersonaje que se pasa como parámetro
- El  getter del nivel de energía del personaje
- Un método que cuando se haga print(personaje) imprima información del personaje: nombre, ubicación, energía.

Se pide crear esta clase y utilizarla exactamente de la siguiente manera (respetar la secuencia de pasos):

1. Crear un personaje p1 que se llame “Bear”
2. Que “Bear” avance (usando una única llamada a Avanzar) 2 casillas hacia el norte, 2 al este.
3. Imprimir información de “Bear”
4. Crear un segundo personaje llamado “Carman”
5. Que “Carman” avance (usando una única llamada a Avanzar) 2 casillas hacia el sur, 1 al oeste y 4 al sur.
6. Que “Bear” avance (usando una única llamada a Avanzar) 7 casilla hacia el este, 2 al norte.
7. Aumenta la energía de “Bear” en 10
8. Imprime el estado de “Bear” y repite el punto 6.
9. Calcula (e imprime) la distancia entre “Bear” y “Carman”

hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
class Personaje:
  def __init__(self,nombre):
    self.posicion=(0,0)
    self.energia=10
    self.nombre=nombre
  

  def __str__(self):
    return f"personaje: \n\tNombre: {self.nombre}"

  def Avanzar(self,listamovimientos):
    for tupla in listamovimientos:
      self.energia=self.energia-tupla[1]
      if tupla[0]=="norte":
        self.posicion=(self.posicion[0],self.posicion[1]+tupla[1])
      if tupla[0]=="sur":
          self.posicion=(self.posicion[0],self.posicion[1]-tupla[1])
      if tupla[0]=="este":
        self.posicion=((self.posicion[0])+tupla[1],self.posicion[1])
      if tupla[0]=="oeste":
        self.posicion=((self.posicion[0])-tupla[1],self.posicion[1])

        
  def ubicacion(self):
    ubicacion=self.posicion
    print(" el personaje se encuentra ubicado en la posicion",ubicacion)
    return ubicacion
    
    


  def cargarenergia(self,unidades):
    unidades=unidades+self.energia
    print("su energía es de",unidades)
    return unidades



  def distancia(self,otro):
    for tupla in otro:
      self.ubicacion=self.ubicacion[0]-otro[0],self.ubicacion[1]-otro[1]
      print(self.ubicacion)
      




    
    
    
    
    
      


  def getenergia(self):
    return self.energia
    


    
    
    


personaje1=Personaje("Jose")
personaje1.Avanzar([ ("norte", 1), ("este", 2) ])
personaje1.ubicacion()
personaje1.distancia([ ("este", 1), ("oeste", 2) ])
otro=Personaje("bear")
otro.avanzar([ ("oeste", 1), ("norte", 1) ])
```

mi pregunta es, para realizar el método distancia se me ocurrió restar la distancia del personaje 1 con la de otro, el tema es que no se me ocurre alguna forma de restar la lista de tuplas del personaje 1 con la de otro

Comment: Te falta primero checkear que te alcance la energía en el método `Avanzar` justo antes de restar la energía tenés que ver que la cantidad de pasos no sea mayor que energía, si es mayor, entonces deberías tirar mensaje y salir de avanzar.

Answer (score 0):

Obviando el hecho de que te falta checkear la energía antes de avanzar (no forma parte de la pregunta pero me parecía justo aclararlo).

Lo que tendrías que hacer es lo siguiente en el método distancia

- Preguntarle a otro su `ubicacion`, luego obtener la `ubicacion` propia, y restar las coordenadas x e y de cada ubicación, elevarlas al cuadrado y sacarle raiz cuadrada (suponiendo que querés la distancia cartesiana y no algúna otra:

```
def distancia(self,otro):
    
    mi_posicion   = self.ubicacion()
    posicion_otro = otro.ubicacion()
    distancia =  ( (mi_posicion[0]-posicion_otro[0])**2 +\ #distancia euclidea
                   (mi_posicion[1]-posicion_otro[1])**2 ) **0.5
    #distancia =  abs(mi_posicion[0]-posicion_otro[0]) +(mi_posicion[1]- 
    #              posicion_otro[1]) #distancia manhatan
    return distancia
```